# run onclick PHP code before redirect to href without using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like something like below:

```
<a href="http://www.someweb.com" onclick="somePHPcode">mylink
```

when I click on "mylink", I'd like to to run "somePHPcode" before redirect to "someweb.com".

Also "somePHPcode" is a PHP function calling or some PHP commands that runs, when mylink is clicked.

I do not like to use `href="javascript:void(0);"` or `href="#" onclick="javascript..."`

Because I need, "someweb.com" link to be viewd.

Comment: you can not use this because php is server side scripting language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is server side code. The onClick event happens on the browser (client side), so you can't do this. You have to use Javascript on the client side (with maybe an Ajax call to the server who can run PHP code).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call PHP function from onclick event , however you can call ajax function and execute your code, Secondly you can use simple form submission to execute your php code and then redirect to your new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `top.location.href` in your javascript function to do redirect after processing the function.

```
<a href="http://www.someweb.com" onclick="javascript:return func();" id="redirect">mylink
```

And use this JS:

```
function func(){
// Your code. Use AJAX if want to execute server side code.

top.location.href= "http://www.someweb.com";
return false;

}
```

Best way is to use the click event handler:

```
$("#redirect").click(function(){
//Your code logic or AJAX Call for server side logic
    top.location.href= "http://www.someweb.com";
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use inline javascript code or the `javascript:` protocol.

Comment: @meagar yeah its best to use event Handlers, but just kept the code for ease of reading for the newbie =)